# send_long_data charset failur

Tags: php, mysql, database, character-encoding

I'm working with German *Umlauten* like `aöü`.

The carset is set to utf8_general on php and database. Insert aswell as select is working fine, only if the data is inserted by using

`$stmt->send_long_data(1,$entry->text);`

These german characters end up as `Ã¼` in the database.
If they are inserted without send_long_data they are getting stored correctly.
I've also tried it out with other columns aswell.

It's allways the same:
Normal Insert --> *Umlaute* stored as äöü. 
Using send_long_data --> stored as Ã¼ and so on.

I've red through [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), but I couldn't really find an answer.

```
$ret ="";
$null= NULL;
$entry->a_date=convert_date($entry->a_date);
$conn=get_sql_connection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT create_entry (?,?,?,?,?)");;
$stmt->bind_param("sbisi",$entry->head,$null,$entry->area,$entry->a_date,$entry->showdate);
$stmt->send_long_data(1,$entry->text);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col);
$stmt->fetch();
$ret = $col;
finish($stmt);
return $ret;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mojibake

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)  If you are using PDO, set the charset attribute of the PDO dsn or via SET NAMES utf8mb4.
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` -- `ü` should have hex of `C3BC` (utf8 encoding), not `FC` (latin1 encoding), not `C383C2BC` (double-encoding).